# Error with expand table ( new opened row got previous value ) using Angular 9 and JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

All code demonstration and behavior is here:

There is no need to explain much here.

Look at the stackblitz, open the first row (click on the row). You will see the details of that row. Click on the second row, the detail from the first row will be override with those details from the second row.

Example video here ( what is problem ) :

https://vimeo.com/543841393

Example of code:

What do I want? So I want that if I open the first row I see the details of the first row, if I open the second row I see the details of the second row and not override my data with each new opening of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using singleDetailsDispatch variable, directly return the book object from the method and call that method inside HTML because when you call getSingleDispatch method, singleDetailsDispatch variable always gets replaced.

```
public getSingleDispatch(book: any) {
return book;
```

}

[fixed stackblitz link heare](https://stackblitz.com/edit/expande-table-error-3xpv4y?file=src/app/parent/parent.component.html)

Comment: I need to update my stackblitz because this is not identical like a my code in project. Your solution no work :/

Comment: your code doesn't work because i make a http by id click request and pass it a new parameter. This is just a example ( basic ) on stackblitz, I need a different solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue exists because singleDetailsDispatch is the common variable and you are updating whenever you click on the table row. Instead of calling a function you can directly pass the book to the child component like below.

```
  <ng-container *ngIf="book.expanded">
    <div class="d-flex row my-1">
      <app-child [dispatchDetails]="book" [closedDetail]="detail"
        class="w-50"></app-child>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: I need to update my stackblitz because this is not identical like a my code in project. Your solution no work :/

Comment: your code doesn't work because i make a http by id click request and pass it a new parameter. This is just a example ( basic ) on stackblitz, I need a different solution.